# How can I pass a custom string as argv[0] to a program

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a C program which uses argv[0] inside the program. I understand that argv[0] is the path of the program being executed. I want to pass a custom string as argv[0] to the program instead of its program name. Is there a way to do this in shell?

I read about exec command. But I am unsure about the usage. `help exec` says I have to pass `exec -a <string>`

1. Is there any other way of doing this?
2. Is there any escape method which I need to use if I am passing *special characters or path of another file* using `exec` command?

To clarify the problem:

I am running a program `prog1`. To enter a particular section in the program I have to give a `SIGALRM` to the program. This step itself was difficult as I had to create a race around condition to send the signal right when the program starts.

```
while true;do ./prog1 2; done & while true; do killall -14 prog1; done
```

The above while loops help me to enter the part of program and that part of program uses `argv[0]` for a system call. This system call is `system(echo something argv[0])`

Is there a way to modify the above while loop and put `;/bin/myprogram` instead of `argv[0]`. 
**Bottom line:** `I need /bin/myprogram` to be executed with the privilege of `prog1` and it's output.

Comment: Why would you not want to use `exec`?

Comment: @rici I couldn't find another possible way of manipulating the program path. I have updated the question and have tried to make it more clear.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you wouldn't want to use `exec`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exec -a` is precisely the way to solve this problem.

There are no restrictions that I know of on the string passed as an argument to `exec`. Normal shell quoting should be sufficient to pass anything you want (as long as it doesn't contain embedded NUL bytes, of course).

The problem with `exec` is that it *replaces* the current shell with the named command. If you just want to run a command, you need to spawn a new shell to be replaced; that is as simple as surrounding the command with parentheses:

```
$ ( exec -a '; /bin/myprogram' bash -c 'echo "$0"'; )
; /bin/myprogram
```

Comment: This is the problem I face. 

I am running a program `prog1`. To enter a particular section in the program I have to give a SIGALRM to the program. This step itself was difficult as I had to create a race around condition to send the signal right when the program starts.

`while true;do ./prog1 2; done & while true; do killall -14 prog1; done`

The above while loops help me to enter the part of program and that part of program uses `argv[0]` for a system call. This system call is `system(echo something argv[0])`

Comment: Is there a way to modify the above while loop and put `;/bin/myprogram` instead of argv[0]. 

Bottom line: I need `/bin/myprogram`to be executed with the privilege of `prog1`and it's output.

Comment: I don't understand this at all: "I need /bin/myprogram to be executed with the privilege of prog1and it's output". Replacing argv[0] has nothing to do with privileges nor does it in any way change the file executed. You should probably ask a new question explaining more directly what you are having trouble with.

Comment: @rici, ...see the question as amended -- the OP is trying to execute a shell injection attack, as the program passes `argv[0]` as an argument into a `system()` call with inadequate escaping.

Comment: @hax, ...rici's answer looks clear enough to -- what's the problem you're having leveraging its advice? `while true; do (exec -a 'prog1;/bin/myprogram' ./prog1 ,); done`

Comment: @rici 

1. prog1 is a program with suid bit set. 
2. The program executes at elevated privilege. I am a low privileged user .
3. There is a system() call in the program which I need to manipulate. 
4. To force the program to make the program make system call I had to use the while loop which I mentioned in my previous comment. [It is as per the program logic]
5. Now this system call executes `echo something argv[0]`
6. If I am able to pass `;/bin/myprog` as `argv[0]` I shall be able to execute ` /bin/myprog` with the privileges of the gid set for prog1

Comment: @charles: ok, that makes sense. But I think I already answered it.

Comment: @rici, I agree, you did. That's why I'm commenting, not adding any answer of my own.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for clarifying. Let me try if the same works.

Comment: @hax: I changed the example.

Comment: Is there a documentation for `exec -a`? UPD: [found](https://askubuntu.com/a/525787/987348).

Answer (score 0):

The brute-force method would be to create your own symlink and run the command that way.

```
ln -s /path/to/mycommand /tmp/newname
/tmp/newname arg1
rm /tmp/newname
```

The main problem with this is finding a secure, race-condition-free way to create the symlink that guarantees you run the command you intend to, which is why `bash` adds a non-standard `-a` extension to `exec` so that you don't need such file-system-based workarounds.

Typically, though, commands restrict their behavioral changes to a small, fixed set of possible names. This means that any such links can be created when the program is first installed, and don't need to be created on the fly. In this scenario, there is no need for `exec -a`, since all possible "virtual" executables already exist.

Comment: Bash itself modifies its behaviour if argv[0] starts with a hyphen. Afaik, that is not normally triggered by way of a symlink.

Comment: Right; in that case `login` is passing `-bash` (or `-sh` or whatever is appropriate) as an argument directly to the `exec*` library call. But lacking an `exec` shell command that accepts `-a` as an argument, the file system is the only way to go.

Comment: Fair enough. If the shell is not bash/ksh/zsh, you might need a different solution.

Comment: I was mostly addressing the "any other way" aspect of the question; since it is tagged `bash`, `exec -a` is absolutely the way to go.